# Shared workspace between MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, matlab

Is it possible to create a shared namespace between MATLAB and Python?

E.g.:

Say, we define x in a Jupyter notebook:

```
x=1.0
```

Then we switch to the MATLAB IDE, and change that same `x`:

```
x=x+1
```

Then we switch back to Jupyter and run:

```
print(x)
```

And we see `2.0`

Is something like this possible?

I don't want to read/write files to mimic this functionality, as that would be to slow for my needs.

Comment: Did you try googling? The MATLAB docs have quite detailed description for different ways to interface MATLAB and Python.

Comment: Yes, I tried googling. Have you tried thinking about the question? There is a difference between calling a function from an external library and properly sharing in-memory variables between two different systems, isn't there?

Comment: You can send variables from the one to the other using well documented functionality. You can not share memory between two processes, the OS won’t allow you to do so, and the internal representation would be different in the two systems. This is why you need inter-process communication as described in the MATLAB docs.

Comment: By the way, asking whether you googled for something specific is not meant to be dismissive. It is good to share what you found and what you attempted so that people here don’t duplicate your effort. If what you found in some specific MATLAB doc pages is not what you need, then tell us.